# PageSpeed ​Insight shows: "generic::internal: APP::1: Abnormal renderer termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1"

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

PageSpeed ​​​​​​​​Insight shows: "general::internal: APP::1: Abnormal display shutdown, status = crashed exit_code = 1"
Here is the link: https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-diszparna-com/irdu04gsqw?hl=hu&form_factor=mobile
What can cause it?

This is a season ticket webshop kotor, so I can't do much.